# Web deployment task failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

[image]
I'm getting this error when I click Build Deployment Package.
I've read a bunch of related post regarding this issue but doesn't seems to answer the questions on my mind T_T.
This is my connection string on my Web.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ProjectPALEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ProjectPal.csdl|res://*/Models.ProjectPal.ssdl|res://*/Models.ProjectPal.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectPAL.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework';" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This is Package/Publish SQL Settings Under Project Properties. This is where I'm having a problem.
[image]
This is the connection string for the source database above.

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectPAL.mdf;integrated security=True;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework';
```

**QUESTIONS:**

- In the Connection string for the source database which is the correct one to use?

  data
  source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectPAL.mdf;integrated
  security=True;user
  instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'; (***this one is what I'm currently using***)

  metadata=res://*/Models.ProjectPal.csdl|res://*/Models.ProjectPal.ssdl|res://*/Models.ProjectPal.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
  connection string=';data
  source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectPAL.mdf;integrated
  security=True;user
  instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'; (**with metadata or none of the above T_T**)
- Where could I get the Connection string for destination database? Sorry It's my first time to deploy a website. I researched but I can't find an answer T_T.
- How could I possibly fixed this error?

**Other Informations:**

- I changed &quot with ' (single quote) after reading this reference [Explicit connection string for EF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2008/12/09/explicit-connection-string-for-ef.aspx)
- I'm using Membership Provider and Role Provider and all my data is saved in ProjectPALEntities

If you need more Info just tell me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's what I did.

I checkout new application from my repository and repeat every steps I did. When I click Import from web.config it automatically created this connection string for me under **Connection string for source database**.

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectPAL.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=EntityFramework;User Instance=True
```

for the **Connection string for destination database** I just leaved it blank because I dunno what to put there. 
When I clicked Build Deployment Package the error message doesn't shows anymore. 
**I wish I knew what to put ont the Connection string for destination database T_T**